# How to save PDFs via an In-App Browser on the iPhone

Tags: ios

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an easy way to allow for PDFs that are opened via an ***in-app browser*** I have created for the iPhone platform to be opened and saved via other PDF viewer apps.  I have no problem making the in-app browser open the PDFs and allowing them to be viewed, I just can't open or save them with other apps like iZip.

When a PDF is opened in Safari, the browser automatically allows me to select which app I want to open and save the pdf in (such as iZip).  When I open the same PDFs via my in-app browser, I cannot save them to iZip.

The ultimate goal is to allow people to view the pdfs in the in-app browser and let them email the PDFs to themselves.  So far I haven't heard of a way to email the pdfs directly from an in-app browser, so I'm hoping that I can at least figure out how to link it out to other pdf viewers that can then be used to save and email the files.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Take a look at `UIDocumentInteractionController`.  There's also some sample code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14630719/1445366